# Experimenting with "big data" and map reduce

Tags: cloud-computing, big-data

I was thinking about experimenting a bit with using mapreduce and such on a dataset we have to see if we can benefit from it in any way.

What route should I go if I want to be able to instantly, without any major modification, deploy my findings to some kind of grid/cloud-system to see if there is any extra benefit to have it scaled in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

"The Cloud" is just a bunch of machines that you don't own. Running on those machines is no different than running on the machines that you *do* own, except that you pay for the time and bandwidth.

If you're using a tool like Hadoop, adding machines is just a matter of configuration (you don't mention platform, but it's the main player in the non-Google map-reduce space, which is just one of the big-data techniques).

My recommendation is that you work through the tutorial, get a single-node implementation of your application running, then *immediately* move to a cloud service like Amazon EC2. You can start with two small instances for about a dollar a day, and increase the number of machines from there.

As a cautionary note: unless you're dealing with 100s of gigabytes of data (and preferably terabytes), I don't think you'll see much benefit of either horizontal scaling or "the cloud." There is a not-insignificant time to setup and teardown map-reduce operations.

Comment: Why immediately?  Didn't you just say that it doesn't matter?

Comment: Um, a cloud is a cloud whether or not you own the machines in question.  To me, the distinction comes when you add a layer on top of the network of machines that essentially behaves like an operating system for groups of computers.  But everyone has their own definition.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree with the "immediately" bit.  When you have one machine, it is too easy to write to a file in one place, and expect that file to exist in another.  Once you've got 2 machines, you notice that you've introduced those dependencies because things don't work.  But if the software scales horizontally, there should be no real difference between 5 and 500 machines other than that the second is faster.  (Note I said "if" and the if in question is always false to some extent...)